# Vuetify preset Essentials cannot find module 'virtual:generated-layouts'

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-router, declaration

I'm starting a Vuetify project with Vue3 and want to build it.
Npm run dev is working fine but npm run build failed on this error :
[image: error message]

Thanks in advance for the help.

I found out with some tests that the blank project from Vuetify works for 2 presets out of 3 (Default and Base) but doesn't work for the preset Essentials because of the error I'm facing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using `vite-plugin-vue-layouts`. This is a Typescript error. You need to add types of virtual module in your project to pass typecheck:

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "types": ['vite-plugin-vue-layouts/client'],
  },
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/JohnCampionJr/vite-plugin-vue-layouts?tab=readme-ov-file#client-types

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i forgot to edit i got  an answer somewhere else : 
https://github.com/vuetifyjs/create-vuetify/issues/42
it was missing the moduleResolution in the compilerOptions